# Acceleration ratio

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

Can anyone please explain why: $$a_1=a_2\tan\alpha $$
[image]

We have 2 **same** cubes placed on a platform, between them there is a wedge which is pushing the cubes in opposite directions. The hard part of the question is to find the ratio between the cubes
accelarion and the wedge acceleration, which is given above, and I cant understand why.

I can't understand the physical idea behind this.

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: Virtual work done by normal force is zero.

Comment: Or you can draw figures at 2 instants and using trigonometry show that their respective displacements are in this ratio. Differentiate twice then.

Comment: triangle is isosceles, right?

Comment: Nothing is given about the traingle except the angle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming isosceles triangle.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

[image]